# How to listen for port in docker?

Tags: linux, shell, docker, devops

I am trying to configure a docker file to run a script once it's ready.

Basically I would like my micro service to wait until another service is available to start. I am following a tutorial in a book, so I have this dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN  apk update && apk upgrade && apk add netcat-openbsd
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD target/${JAR_FILE} /usr/share/theexplorer/theexplorer.jar
ADD run.sh run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh
CMD ./run.sh
EXPOSE 8761
```

And I have this script (run.sh):

```
echo "********************************************************"
echo "Waiting for the configuration server to start on port $CONFIGSERVER_PORT"
echo "********************************************************"
while ! `nc -z configserver $CONFIGSERVER_PORT `; do sleep 3; done
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>> Configuration Server has started"
java -jar /usr/share/theexplorer/theexplorer.jar
```

But the value of $CONFIGSERVER_PORT is null. I have no idea how this variable should be available, since I didn't pass any parameter while calling run.sh. So, **How should I set the $CONFIGSERVER_PORT?** Is there any smart way to know the port of the services that my service is dependent?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Pass the variable in your run command like `docker run -e CONFIGSERVER_PORT=<PORT> myservice`

Comment: Is the config server running in a separate container or directly on the host? Or is it started in the same container?

Comment: config server is in a separate container on my machine

Answer (score 5):

`docker run -itd -p 5555:8761 myimage/myimage` maps the host port 5555 to the container port 8761. It works the same for the "other" service you would be waiting on, so at this point you aren't depending on dynamic host port mapping. This is how you can know the port of each of your services.

Your running service container would be reachable on localhost:5555 in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I believe that @Munchkin is more accurate. I would like to pass the port to my script. But I found out that it kinda easy with docker compose